# Photoshop CS5 - Export flattened layers in groups to their own files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I have 10 groups of flattened images which need to be trimmed, exported to png and placed in their own file with the same name as the group.  I can't find the script to do this anywhere and was wondering if anyone knows how or where I could find this.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but does this do close to what you want? Can export each layer to a PNG:

File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files

There's also

File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files

which does the same for Layer Comps (sets of visible layers). If paired with a script that goes through first and flattens each layer group, should be perfect fit.

Performance can be an issue however in complex docs. Slooooww as at CS4 on top spec PC!